# Ggplot2: plot avgSessionDuration from GA as a bar plot? Formal class 'Period' [package "lubridate"]

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've a df with months and `Avg. Session Duration` from Google Analytics.

Definition of `Avg. Session Duration`: The average duration (in seconds) of users' sessions.

This column I've converted from seconds to minutes using `lubridate`:

```
library(lubridate)

df$avgSessionDuration <-  seconds_to_period(df$avgSessionDuration)
```

But when I try to plot this as a simple bar chart, I'm getting and empty plot:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=mes, y = avgSessionDuration, label = avgSessionDuration)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

[image]

**dput:**

```
structure(list(mes = c("Apr", "Aug", "Dec", "Feb", "Jan", "Jul", 
"Jun", "Mar", "May", "Nov", "Oct", "Sep"), avgSessionDuration = new("Period", 
    .Data = c(40.3422263169386, 15.0267821554301, 58.2952632067657, 
    23.8959081801318, 48.6127812066904, 52.4427333243062, 28.2065306406772, 
    7.08722136893016, 53.9021568123918, 6.21260764666937, 45.1247832993034, 
    35.057865957604), year = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0), month = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), day = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), hour = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), minute = c(6, 7, 6, 11, 12, 6, 7, 7, 
    6, 8, 7, 7))), row.names = c(NA, -12L), totals = list(list(
    sessions = "52429423", sessionDuration = "2.6206981539E10", 
    avgSessionDuration = "499.8525644464941")), minimums = list(
    list(sessions = "45875", sessionDuration = "1.6438276E7", 
        avgSessionDuration = "264.72602881964076")), maximums = list(
    list(sessions = "932025", sessionDuration = "6.17676652E8", 
        avgSessionDuration = "981.1245110604924")), isDataGolden = TRUE, rowCount = 365L, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% separate(avgSessionDuration, c("A", "B")) %>% ggplot(aes(x=mes, y = A, label = A)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```